# Business Central Dynamics 365 Sales Connection Setup Error in Sync Queues for Item, Opportunity, Resource and Others

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-business-central

I am working on Business Central on a demo tenant. I have set up Common Data Service Connection Setup and Dynamics 365 Sales Connection Setup. When I run a initial sync in a new company made with production - setup data only the Customer, Contact, Currency and Vendor Entities sync job are being run and finished successfully(so it is written in status of the wizard and I can find new account in CRM which were previously created in Business Central). Before running the sync I removed the CRM Customer Engagement licence from the integration user and set him up in CRM as a non-interactive type of user.

The error I receive from the Item, Opportunity and Resource entity are the following:

> Open record "An error occurred when communicating with Common Data
>   Service. Detailed description: 'Product' entity doesn't contain
>   attribute with Name = 'bcbi_companyid' and NameMapping = 'Logical'.
>   MetadataCacheDetails: ProviderType=Dynamic, StandardCache=Tru"
>
> Open record "An error occurred when communicating with Common Data
>   Service. Detailed description: 'Opportunity' entity doesn't contain
>   attribute with Name = 'bcbi_companyid' and NameMapping = 'Logical'.
>   MetadataCacheDetails: ProviderType=Dynamic, StandardCache"
>
> Open record "An error occurred when communicating with Common Data
>   Service. Detailed description: 'Product' entity doesn't contain
>   attribute with Name = 'bcbi_companyid' and NameMapping = 'Logical'.
>   MetadataCacheDetails: ProviderType=Dynamic, StandardCache=Tru"

Other entities in initial sync are not run and i believe that the sync stopped on those errors. I cannot finish the initial sync. After returning the licence and trying again to run the error remains and the sync is not finished. Am I missing a company property somewhere ?

Comment: I expirience the same problem while creating CRM-SalesOrders in Business Central:

    'SalesOrder' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'bcbi_companyid' and NameMapping = 'Platform'.

Comment: I have opened a Microsoft support ticket, they say it is a open issue and don't know when it will be resolved.

Comment: Good to know. I've opened a MS ticket too, but did not receive a reply yet. Guess it will be the same as yours.